# ACF file - How to force download instead of open in the browser

Tags: pdf

1. Using ACF, ACF file field PDF - How to force a file to download instead of open in the browser?
2. Any proper way to disable the file URL/Path to view in inspect mode (Eg: scribd.com)

   ```
    <a href="<?php the_field( 'download_pdf' ); ?>" download>Download File</a>
   ```

Comment: You should check with the ACF support team for this.  ACF is a third-party plugin and has it's own way of working.

Comment: Part 2 of your question is not clear and you should post it as a separate question.  Also, if I understand your question, this is not specific to ACF or PDFs.

Comment: @MarcGuay - Part 2 - I need to hide the file field URL (PDF), if some one to inspect the code.

Answer (score 0):

Trying using the `download` attribute on the anchor.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attributes

Comment: Yes - That's working, and I already mentioned the 'download' attribute on above shared code. But that not a proper way actually!